# さくらのレンタルサーバにpython3をインストールする方法について

Tags: python

さくらのレンタルサーバpython3をインストールできないため、解決方法を教えていただきたいです。

`http://ura22.sakura.ne.jp/pycgi/preparation.html`
上記のサイトの通り、pythonのバージョン以外は全く同じコマンドを実行しました。
■実行コマンド

```
mkdir local
mkdir local/src
cd local/
cd src/
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.3/Python-3.4.3.tar.xz --no-check-        certificate
tar -xjf Python-3.4.3.tar.xz
cd Python-3.4.3
./configure --prefix=$HOME/local/python/
make
make install
```

.cshrcに下記を追記

```
set path = ($HOME/local/python/bin)
setenv PYTHON $HOME/local/python/lib
```

この状態で`python3`を入力すると、`-bash: python3: command not found`となってしましいます。

よろしくお願いたします。

※関係がないとは思いますが、`http://blog.chibiegg.net/2015/05/05_23_791.htm`を参考に、python2でdjangoの環境をつくりました。

Comment: さくらのレタルサーバーはわかりませんが Freebsd なのですね。`./configure` `make` `make install` はエラーなく正常終了したということで合ってますか？ `$HOME/local/python/bin/` の下に `python3` はありますか？

Answer (score 2):

まず、参考先のサイトの記述内容はソースパッケージの圧縮形式が、tar.bz2 の場合での解説となっています。
一方、3.4.3の場合、3.4.3.tgz が公式の[ダウンロードページ](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-343/)のリンク（[Gzipped source tarball](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.3/Python-3.4.3.tgz)）となっています。

ですので、wget は

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.3/Python-3.4.3.tgz --no-check-certificate
```

とすべきではないでしょうか？（tar.xz 版も存在はするようですが、何のために存在するのか私にはわかりません。）

.tgz の場合、解凍時の tar のオプションが違ってきます。

```
tar -xzf Python-3.4.3.tar.tgz
```

参考までに、.tar.xz の場合は：

```
tar -xJf Python-3.4.3.tar.xz
```

です。また、Python の最新バージョンは、[3.5.1](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-351/) です。

Comment: ~/.bashrcに
`export PATH=$HOME/local/python/bin:$PATH`
と追記することで解決しました。

ご指摘ありがとうございました！